# Html's title cannot be refreshed in SpringBoot project

Tags: html, spring-boot

I'm working with a SpringBoot project. And i want to change the html's . But it's not working for me, still show the default value `Title`. And this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Home</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

But i found that if i just run this html file alone, the title will show correct。 
Is there cache in SpringBoot?

Comment: Build your project.

Comment: I got the problem. There's bug in JRebel. It's okay when without JRebel. @AmmarAli

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by JRebel. I got the correct result without JRebel.